# Show that the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra is free over the set of propositional variables

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, algebraic-logic

> Show that the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra is free over the set of propositional variables.

I was given that statement to prove. My lecturer said we need to show that any map from said set to a given Boolean algebra B can be extended to a homomorphism from the [Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindenbaum%E2%80%93Tarski_algebra) to B.

I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: Is it for *propositional calculus*, isn't it?

Comment: I made a couple of changes to your post.  First, the body of the Question should have the complete problem statement, not relying on the title alone to bear this burden.  The second begins to address what is meant by the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra in your context.  As this is an assigned exercise, it may not occur to you that the assignment comes with a certain amount of context that will be unknown to your Readers.  Presumably the theory $\mathbf T$ involved the the basic theory of propositional calculus.  Feel free to rollback my edits if they have unintentionally changed your meaning.